# Change text every 3 seconds with fade effect

Tags: jquery, text

I want to change the text of a p every 3 seconds with the jquery "Fade Effect" :

```
<p class="first">Conected</p>
```

to

```
<p class="second">2547</p>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use setInterval https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.setInterval

```
setInterval(function() {
    $('p').fadeOut(500, function() {
        var $this = $(this);
        $this.text($this.text() == 'Connected' ? '2457' : 'Connected');        
        $this.toggleClass('first second');        
        $this.fadeIn(500);
    });
}, 3000);​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/wirey00/E4xqg/

Comment: Nice. I can see one might use: $(this).text($(this).text() == 'Need Help?' ? 'Click here!' : 'Need Help?'); on an anchor instead of a P just to draw attention to a link.

Answer (score -1):

setInterval or wait

setInterval
http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_timing.asp

JQuery Wait
http://api.jquery.com/delay/